# How can I customize the SML/NJ interactive loop?

Tags: sml, smlnj

I'm new to Standard ML and I'm trying to get my head around the SML/NJ runtime environment. I want to adapt it to my needs. Specifically, I want to:

- Use IntInf by default
- Prevent it from truncating strings and IntInf to 70 characters.

Here's what I've found in my 8+ hours reading documentation and experimenting.

I can overload IntInf on top of int with the command

```
open IntInf;
```

I can control how many characters in a string are displayed with the variable Control.Print.stringDepth. For example, this will let it display 1000 characters before truncating:

```
Control.Print.stringDepth := 1000;
```

How do I do the same for IntInf values? Can I set the depth to be infinite (that is, no truncation at all)?

Is opening IntInf the best way to overload int with IntInf?

Finally, how to I make this all load automatically at runtime so that when I invoke "sml" it's in my default environment?

---

Edit: I've since found out there is an option called Control.Print.intinfDepth that can be set to a large number (say, 999999). I don't know how to make it infinite, though.

My other questions still remain unanswered.

---

Edit: I ran across this [set of SML/NJ customizations for a class at Kansas State](http://people.cis.ksu.edu/~stough/sml/smlcus.sml). To display my own banner message and avoid displaying "val it = true : bool" I need to test the return value of SMLofNJ.exportML. If it's true, the heap image was just restored (ie, started up) and I can display a message. If it's false, the heap image was just saved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I make this all load automatically at runtime so that when I invoke "sml" it's in my default environment?

You need to create a *heap image* to be run by the `sml` script, which you can then symbolically link to.  To avoid complications of bootstrapping, I usually give my heap image a different name; for example; `sml-nw` for SML/NJ with support for [noweb](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/noweb/).

The basic primitive you need to create a heap image is `SMLofNJ.exportML`.  Here's how you use it:

1. Set up everything the way you want it by, e.g., `open IntInf` and setting all your `Control.Print` variables.  (You could try setting Control.Print`things to`valOf Int.maxInt`, which is the closest thing to infinity.)
2. Create a new heap image by `SMLofNJ.exportML "mysml"`.  When you start your customized version, you'll begin right after the call to `exportML`.  Read  [the documentation](http://www.smlnj.org/doc/SMLofNJ/pages/smlnj.html).  Play around; there are a lot of ways to use this primitive.
3. Copy the heap image (maybe `mysml.x86-linux`) to the installation directory for heap images (on my installation, `/usr/lib/smlnj/bin/.heap`, but you can follow clues in the `sml` script to be sure)
4. Create a script `mysml` that is a symbolic link to the `sml` script.

In the old days this was enough, but I haven't been using SML/NJ for several years now.  I also found a [somewhat outdated example](http://people.cis.ksu.edu/~stough/sml/smlcus.html) on the web.

Comment: Thanks. I did find that in the documentation and it works, but I figured there must be a better way that preserves the usual "welcome" banner message and doesn't display "val it = true : bool" upon startup. You use Moscow ML normally?

Comment: @Barry: if you want to avoid a 'val it = ...' message you'll have to figure out how to make a call to the top-level read/eval/print loop.  Compiler.Interact.interact looks promising, but it's inexplicably missing from my installation.

Comment: @Barry: These days my functional programming is lagely OCaml or Haskell.  When I compile legacy SML code it is usually with MLton.

Comment: @Barry: I've now reported a bug to SML/NJ and they've agree that the functionality advertised in Compiler.Interact.interact seems to have gone missing...

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

http://archives.devshed.com/forums/programming-132/big-integers-in-sml-nj-97t-316791.html

Not sure about infinite question.